# Uncaught TypeError: e_type.appendchild is not a function | while adding element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Want to add a new paragraph in html using java script  create element property but getting error of invalid append function.

```
**// Html code :-**
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnReq.png)

```
<button onclick= "add()">Click me to add New text.. </button>

**// JavaScript code :-** 

function add()    
{       
    var e_type = document.createElement("p"); 
    var text = document.createTextNode("Hello Again..!");   
    e_type.appendchild(text); // error- e_type.appendchild is not a function    
    var parent_type = document.getElementById("self");          
    parent_type.appendchild(e_type);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive: It's `appendChild` (capital `C`), not `appendchild`.

Comment: **Thanks @ T.J. Crowder**